# How to resolve DexArchiveBuilderException for Gradle?

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin

I have been getting the following build issue in Android Studio 3.0.1, and I have been unable to resolve it. I cannot run my app in the  meantime.

```
com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException:com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to process /home/Code/StudioProjects/aac/app/build/intermediates/transforms/instantRunSlicer/debug/7
```

...

The Gradle Console says the NoSuchElementException plays a role, however it doesn't link this exception to anything in my code.

```
Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.LinkedList$ListItr.previous(LinkedList.java:905)
```

My build.gradle is as follows.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "this.app.id.is" // had to change appID for privacy
        minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.5.+'  // Third-party library. Copyright 2016, Arthur Teplitzki, 2013, Edmodo, Inc
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.0'
}
```

If anyone has any ideas on how to resolve this error, the help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your run configurations Edit Run Configurations window, disable advanced profiling field in run configurations

Comment: It is disabled and it makes no difference. Thanks though.